# inject GPS data for indoor fly matrice 600

Tags: gps, dji-sdk

Drone: matrice 600
I want to fly indoor where there is no GPS signal.
i know the GPS location from sensor array that i have,
is it possible to inject the GPS location to the drone?

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2018, it is not possible to inject GPS location into DJI drones. A possible workaround is to use the Onboard SDK to write your own position control algorithm, and command the drone using a control mode that does not require GPS, for example attitude control.

Comment: I don't want to develop the flight control Application, I just want to inject my GPS. I find that there is Payload-SDK that i can use, but i didn't find how to push data to the FCU (just reading information..)